# CSharp Adding my site url path to the front of a Hyperlink

Tags: c#, anchor

I am having an issue. I have page urls coming in as strings from my DB via csharp access identifier.

Example of cshtml line:

```
<a href="@data.PageURL." target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">@data.PageTitle</a>
```

When I try to click on the link the link appears as:

```
https://www.MyAPP.com/dmr/home/www.LINKURL.com
```

How to I get the clickable anchor tag to only display

```
www.LINKURL.com
```

Any ideas or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Razor or C#.

The browser doesn't know that it's a domain - it is interpreting it as a file path. Use a protocol `http://`, `https://` or `//` (this means use the same protocol as the current page).

You might consider adding data validation before saving potentially invalid URLs in your database.